# Visual studio C++ parameter indentation

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Is there a setting somewhere that tells VS to use the same indentation rules throughout?  When I declare a class, it indents as expected

```
class AAAAAA
{
public:
   AAAAAA(
      int this_is_ok)
   {
   }
};

class BBBBB
{
public:
   BBBBB(
      int this_is_also_ok);
};
```

When I define the functions for the class, the indentation rules for the parameters change

```
BBBBB::BBBBB(
             int why_does_this_not_follow_the_same_rules
             )
{
}


void funky(
           int why_does_this_not_follow_the_same_rules
           )
{
}
```

I'd like to keep the same 3 space indentation because some of the class/function names are very long and it makes the formatting difficult for maintenance when classes or function name changes length.

Comment: Both indentation styles are horrific. The first would be acceptable if you'd also dropped the `)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2015, you can find the option for this behavior under Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Formatting > Indentation > Within parentheses, align new lines when I type them:

[image]

Comment: Works on 2013 too.  Unfortunately 2008 and 2010 do not have that option.  Also works if you highlight text and Ctrl-K Ctrl-F.